# IBM Worklight - Clicking a button to navigate to another HTML page doesn't work (multiple page application)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to follow [this guide](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/03_02_Building_a_multi_page_application.pdf). I reach a problem when i try to change the HTML file when the user clicks a button.

This is my script:

```
<script>
        window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;
        $("#btnPromo").click(function(){
            $("#pagePort").load("pages/MainPage.html", function(){
                alert("loaded!");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And this is my core HTML file (auto generated by Worklight):

```
<body onload="WL.Client.init({})" id="content" style="display: none;">
<!--application UI goes here-->
<div data-role="page" id="pagePort">
    <div id="header" align="center">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div>
            <input type="image" name="btnPromo" src="images/btnHotPromo.png" width="75%"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="image" name="btnMall" src="images/btnMall.png" width="75%"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="image" name="btnOutlet" src="images/btnOutlet.png" width="75%"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="image" name="btnAbout" src="images/btnAbout.png" width="75%"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to change the `#pagePort` to `MainPage.html` every time the user clicks on `#btnPromo`.

Comment: What is your Worklight version? Do you have any errors? Look at the developer tools console in Chrome when clicking the button.

Comment: @IdanAdar Thanks for your help, i have fixed it. Its a beginner mistake :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is i **forgot to add** the `$(function(){});` at the start of the code, so the code should be :

```
$(function(){
        $("#btnPromo").click(function(){
            $("#pagePort").load("pages/MainPage.html", function(){
                alert("loaded!");
            });
        });
});
```

And everything will be OK :D

Comment: Ups..sorry i forgot it, sometimes i should wait 24 hours to mark it. Thanks :D