# css background image not showing with ibm worklight

Tags: css, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to use a background image in my Worklight project. Everything works fine when i tried to run my code without worklight (I'm using notepad++ and run it on my browser).

However, my background image suddenly disappear when I use Worklight (i mean i copy - paste the code and edit the references), but other image (which use the `src` tag) is still there.

This is my css code:

```
body{
    background:url(../images/background.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This is the screenshot :

[image]

Comment: What does "before" mean? What does "moving code to the worklight environment" mean? How did you move it? where to did you move it? What is in your images folder? How does the HTML look like? Edit the question with this information.

Comment: @IdanAdar sorry for confusing you. Please see my edited question. Thanks

Comment: @IdanAdar please see my other question about multiple pages.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185260/ibm-worklight-click-a-button-to-go-to-another-page-multiple-page-application
Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By following the next steps, I saw my background image in the application:

1. Created a new Worklight project and application
2. Placed an image file in the images folder (myProjects\apps\myApp\common\images)
3. In the CSS file:

   > body {
   >        background:url("../images/background.jpg");
   >       }
4. Build all and deploy
5. Previewed via Worklight Console

Like I mentioned in my comment - edit your question and add your HTML and CSS.
Also make sure you have placed the image in the images folder.

Comment: Sorry its still not working, please see my edited question (with screenshot). Thanks :D

Comment: It's working fine for me - try with a new application and see if only THAT works, then start making changes and check when it fails.

Comment: Yes, its working perfectly with your way and center center fixed css. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

Check the image url path. or add the image to the worklight project folder and check.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have checked all of it, and all of them is fine

Comment: Add quotes to that url.            background:url("../images/background.png") no-repeat;